# C to ARM ASM converter

Tags: iphone, assembly, arm

Is there any converter to convert a C function into ARM (v6) ASM code or I need to do it manually ?

I am trying to gain the performance of a C function on Iphone.

Comment: The iPhone SDK does this for you... why do you think you need to do anything special?

Comment: Unless you are trying to do something *very* special, I'd take a look over the C code.

Comment: Uh, C *becomes* assembly code eventually anyways. Converting the C code to assembler isn't going to help unless you proceed to tune the assembly manually, which requires knowledge that it doesn't sound like you have.

Comment: I guess yes, I need to tweak the assembly to gain the performance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing you're in XCode, open the source file and select `Build => Show Assembly Code`.

Comment: I think that is what I need but definitely good finiding, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

tool that does it is called compiler :) take a look here: http://www.keil.com/arm/